# Finding the number of each type of fruit bought

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A man has $\$100$. If we have that:

- $1$ apple costs $\$1$
- $1$ oranges cost $\$0.05$
- $1$ watermelon costs $\$5$

and the man buys exactly $100$ pieces of fruit with exactly $\$100$ (He must buy at least  1 fruit from each category), then how many of each fruit did he buy? Could you please explain the method used? Thanks :)

Comment: He may bought 100 apples and nothing else.

Comment: Many "Hundred Fowl" variants have non-unique solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your edit, we must be able to purchase individual oranges, for otherwise the $100$ fruits for $\$100$ situation is impossible. (Why?)

Suppose $x,y,z$ are (respectively) the numbers of apples, oranges, and watermelons bought. Observe that one orange costs $\$0.05$ (why?). The amount he paid for apples was the cost per apple times the number of apples--that is, $1.00\cdot x=x$ dollars--likewise, he paid $0.05y$ dollars for the oranges and $5z$ dollars for the watermelons. Hence, since he paid $\$100$ in total, then $$100=x+.05y+5z\tag{$\heartsuit$}$$ On the other hand, he bought $100$ fruits, so we know that $$100=x+y+z\tag{$\clubsuit$}$$ Subtracting $(\heartsuit)-(\clubsuit)$ gives us $$0=-.95y+4z,$$ whence multiplication by $20$ yields $$0=-19y+80z$$ and so $$19y=80z.$$ Now, we know that $y,z$ are integers, so since $19$ is prime and is not a factor of $80,$ then $19$ is a factor of $z$. In particular, we know that $z$ is positive, so $z=19k$ for some integer $k\ge1,$ whence $y=80k.$ Now, putting those back into $(\clubsuit)$ gives us $$100=x+80k+19k=x+99k.\tag{$\clubsuit'$}$$ Since $x,k$ are positive integers, then it follows by $(\clubsuit')$ that $x=k=1,$ so he bought an apple, $80$ oranges, and $19$ watermelons.

Comment: Nice. You're missing a k in equation club-prime, though. Due to the remark added in the question, Case 2 cannot be the case.

Comment: @HSN: Thanks! I'll adjust.

Answer (score 1):

Its clear that the man cannot buy oranges because for only $\$5$, he has purchased 100 of them.

Clearly, he couldn't have bought watermelons either, because he could only buy 20 for $\$100$.

That leaves apples, which he can easily buy 100 for $\$100$.

Note that, in general, solving this type of problem requires linear algebra using a system of equations, and even worse, since we're dealing with whole pieces of fruit, we need to guarantee that the solutions are positive whole numbers. This system has only two equations ($1*A+0.05*B+5*C=100$ and $A+B+C=100$) with three unknowns, so in general it's not necessarily true that there is only one solution in the positive integers. In some cases there might be no solutions, or 5 solutions, or an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: ah, you're right, whoops!

Answer (score 0):

Joking, I commented that he may bought $100$ apples and nothing else. But I soon find out that's the only solution.

First, he didn't buy any oranges. Otherwise he have to buy at least $100$ oranges, but only gave $5$ dollars. He has no way to use the $\$95$ left.

Second, he must use all money to buy apples, since apple is cheaper than watermelon. If he bought any watermelon he can't buy enough fruits.